# Any known ERC20 Tokens that don't implement the decimals() function?

Tags: tokens, decimals

Are there any ERC20 Tokens that don't implement the decimals() functionality?

Answer (score 0):

It's enable by default.

A quote from the openzeppelin docs

`By default, ERC20 uses a value of 18 for decimals. To use a different value, you will need to override the decimals() function in your contract.`

You can find more info about that here:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/erc20#a-note-on-decimals